# Mediatek MT7630E wifi adapter (hp) unstable wifi connection (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, adapter

I just installed the driver from github for **Mediatek MT7630E wifi adapter (hp)** initially it worked fine but after the reboot if became very unstable, it is detecting the wifi networks but doesn't contects to them. Sometimes it does automatically connects but only for few minutes. I looked at the similar problems on this platform and changed the wifi.powersaver = 3 to 2. still no change.
Here is the details of my adapter. It will be a big help if someone could suggest what is wrong and how to fix it.

````
lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: fc:4d:d4:50:53:06
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7630e driverversion=4.15.0-106-generic firmware=112.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:c2600000-c26fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 08
       serial: a0:48:1c:0b:5d:21
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c2504000-c2504fff memory:c2500000-c2503fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s20u1
       serial: 4a:d7:c9:c9:65:08
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.29 link=yes multicast=yes
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.```
--------------------------------------------------------
$ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
08:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 08)
0a:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520] (rev ff)```
--------------------------------------------------------
```$ ifconfig 
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:48:1c:0b:5d:21  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp0s20u1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4a:d7:c9:c9:65:08  
          inet addr:192.168.42.29  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7899:a0c6:fe1d:f847/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11108 errors:3 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:3
          TX packets:11228 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8184294 (8.1 MB)  TX bytes:2029929 (2.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5393 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5393 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:445082 (445.0 KB)  TX bytes:445082 (445.0 KB)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
$ iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          
enp0s20u1  no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.
------------------------------------------------

It will be a big help if someone could suggest what is wrong and how to fix it.
````